# How to maintain HTML mark -up as-is in an google sheet cell without breaking the html tag

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use google sheet to add complete HTML of an email in a cell where I have variables for text, image src, href src etc.

Now I am using google script to replace tags with the values so that I can copy the complete html and paste it in the email marketing system.

I am doing this because my email marketing system does not support variables.

But, I have noticed, when I paste HTML template markup in a cell, the google sheet adds an extra set of `""` around the existing `""`.

For example, if this is the HTML I paste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<a href="https://www.Google.com">Visit Google</a>


</body>
</html>
```

This will be changed into this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<a href=""https://www.Google.com"">Visit Google</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Notice:

```
<a href="https://www.Google.com">Visit Google</a>
```

Google sheet is adding extra set ok `""` around my href src. Same problem with all the tags.

```
<a href=""https://www.Google.com"">Visit Google</a>
```

My concern is if google sheet can maintain html as-is in a cell or not? Any solution to this problem?

Comment: 1.Use single quotes. 2. Why not directly paste it in script editor as a html file?

Comment: Because I'm creating this sheet to edit content in the HTML easily for users. Who can simple add values in the variable and on button click, my script will replace variable with values in the HTML.

Comment: Using script editor won't solve the problem that I'm looking to solve.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template

Comment: Hi @TheMaster I am not 100% sure how to use the html-template from the doc. Is there any example / steps to follow? Just fyi.. I am not trying ton construct HTML, I already have HTML of full email template. Just trying to find an easy way for users to add value in variables in google sheet, and a button script will execute the script that will find variables in the HTML code and replace it. So users can paste the new updated HTML code and use it in email marketing system.

Comment: See the guide in the first line. You can use the template>use printing scriplets>evaluate to htmlOutput> getContent() - get the evaluated html as String>  Provide it in a text box or a new cell in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Just enter the strings shown below into those cells in Sheet1 which no quotations and then run the script and you'll see your html
//A1=My First Heading
//A2=My first paragraph.
//A3=http://google.com
//A4=Visit Google

function displayEmailHtml() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,4,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html=Utilities.formatString('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p><a href="%s">%s</a>/body></html>',vA[0][0],vA[1][0],vA[2][0],vA[3][0]);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'My Email Html');
}
```

To answer your second question try this:

```
function displayEmailHtml() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,4,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html=Utilities.formatString('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>%s</h1>\n<p>%s</p>',vA[0][0],vA[1][0]);
  html+=Utilities.formatString('\n<a href="%s">%s</a>\n</body>\n</html>',vA[2][0],vA[3][0]);
  html=html.replace(/>/g,'&gt');
  html=html.replace(/</g,'&lt');
  html=Utilities.formatString('<pre>%s</pre>',html);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'My Email Html');
}
```

- [Utilities.formatString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(String,Object...))

Comment: Hi @Cooper thank you for the code. It does work and it is great. In my use-case, I am not looking to get HTML output. I would like to display the raw html markup after the update has been done. How can we do that?

Comment: Thank you @Cooper for the update. it is working and that's exactly what I am look for. Question for you: In this approach we are following the order approach in which 1st variable relates to 1st cell value, second variable relates to 2nd cell value and so on...Is it possible to assign variables like "heading1", "href_url", "button_text" etc? Second question is: Where this is coming from "%s"? is it declared somewhere? why "%s"?

Comment: Since we are following sequential approach, if we have one line like `<a href="%s">%s</a> ` is this approach going to be very accurate and always replace whatever variable comes first even if we have a number of variables in the same line?

Comment: I also testing adding the whole email template. Since email template HTML code is quite a lot as compared to just one line, only one line is coming in the output. It might be a lot of work to put together whole html template in one single and not sure if that will work or not as complete HTML email template may have a lot of tags, special characters etc. Your thoughts? any way to make improvements to support full HTML email template?

Comment: H @Cooper, I see you have updated the code but making it work for a real email template can be a challenge. How this approach will work with this example template that includes complete HTML markup / CSS: [https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_cafe](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_cafe)